# laravel spatie permission hasPermissionTo not work with string

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I want to test a feature in which the user checks to have this permission for the operation.
When I pass a Permission model it returns a good result, but when I giv the the permission name in a parameter it runs an error.

composer.json

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.3",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5"
```

Test.php

```
$permission = 'do-something';
$permissionModel = Permission::create([
   'name' => $permission,
   'guard_name' => 'sanctum'
]);

$user = User::factory()->create();
$user->givePermissionTo($permissionModel);

$user->hasPermissionTo($permissionModel); // return true
$user->hasPermissionTo($permission); // fail with error:
Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\PermissionDoesNotExist: There is no permission named `do-something` for guard `sanctum`.
```

I want to use the string solution, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not `$user->givePermissionTo($permission);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the permission name is exist in your permissiom table then try the following command:

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

Then

```
php artisan cache:clear
```