# Spatie \ Permission \ Exceptions \ PermissionDoesNotExist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I was trying to use spatie role and permission but when i try to update role and permission it gives me the above error and highlights the if statement in the function below located inside the user model

```
public static function roleHasPermissions($role,$permissions){

    $hasPermission=true;

    // dd($role);

    // dd($perm);

    foreach($permissions as $permission){

        if(!$role->hasPermissionTo($permission)){

            $hasPermission=true;

        }

    }

    return $hasPermission;

}
```

To update role and permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel spatie permission hasPermissionTo not work with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263108/laravel-spatie-permission-haspermissionto-not-work-with-string)

Answer (score 0):

The error simply implies that the permission you are checking for has not been created.

Check to ensure that the permission has been created before attempting to assign to a role.